# Remove the referances from asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, reference

I have added a reference called Interop.Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel to my webpage.
Now I don't need it. So I decided to remove it from the website. But I don't know how to remove that reference. Can Anyone help me?
I am a newbie. So I am asking this stupid question.

Comment: I suppose that you have a dll on your bin that belong to that. Simple remove that dll, and any other file relative to that dll (eg the same name but different extensions) And also you can check your web.config to see if also this exist there on a line.

Comment: Ya I have dll in bin folder. But I don't know xml very well so I cant check in web.config file.

Comment: @Aristos - It's not quite that simple - if there's any code that uses that DLL it also needs to be removed, plus any `Imports` statements.  Then the project/solution needs to be rebuilt and republished.

Comment: No I am not using any code from that dll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To remove a reference in Visual Basic**

- In Solution Explorer, double-click the My Project node for the project.
- In the Project Designer, click the References tab.
- Click the Remove button.

**To remove a reference in Visual C#**

- In Solution Explorer, open the References node under the project node.
- Right-click a reference and click Remove.

For more details, please refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/wkze6zky.aspx link.

**Please mark this answer useful if this solve your problem.**